# What creates "data-preserver-spaces" span tags in user-generated content?

Tags: user-generated-content

I've noticed that some user-generated rich content on a site that I maintain has become littered with invisible `span` tags carrying data attributes:

```html
<span data-preserver-spaces="true">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </span><em><span
data-preserver-spaces="true">consequatur</span></em><span data-preserver-spaces="true">
explicabo soluta. Eos quam temporibus rerum ullam perferendis, architecto velit nulla.</span>
```

I assume this was injected by a browser extension or something on the user's machine, or perhaps was pasted from other software. Can anyone identify the source?

A [web search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22data-preserver-spaces%22) just turned up more examples of the same phenomenon on other websites using a variety of CMSs.

Comment: I don't know of any rich content editing support that's natively built into web browsers. I'd imagine that all the CMSs that you were seeing this in use some common rich editing JavaScript and CSS library that is causing the problem.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content)

Comment: `contenteditable` is usually accompanied by a load of JavaScript to control the formatting of elements within it though.  On its own, it is pretty much just text.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I'm not sure what you're getting at. I think you're trying to refute my assumption but I'm not sure how the points you've made relate to it.

Comment: I wouldn't assume that it is a browser or extension behavior opposed to a JavaScript plugin for CMS behavior.

Comment: 1) I'm familiar with my site and don't know it to have this behavior, 2) only a small amount of the content on my site is affected, and 3) other websites affected in the wild appear to span a diverse range of tech stacks.

Comment: In that case, do you have logs from which you can get the user agent that was used when submitting the data that had that in it?

Comment: Maybe, but I don't think it's worth trying to reconstruct that information; I expect all it would contribute is narrowing down from 2–3 likely browsers to one, and we're not at a point in reasoning of needing to apply a process of elimination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If text is copied and pasted from Grammarly editor HTML like this can be inserted.

Comment: This is the answer. Check out this forum post where someone is complaining about Grammarly including `data-preserver-spaces` junk when they copy-paste from it: https://themes.artbees.net/forums/topic/how-to-use-sticky-header-on-mobile/